# How to use tt font in mathtt in ConTeXt?

Tags: fonts, context

When using a specific mono font in ConTeXt I want to have this font as `\tt` font which should also affect `\mathtt`. So how can I use my main tt font as math tt font?

MWE:

```
\definefontfamily [test] [rm] [TeX Gyre Pagella]
\definefontfamily [test] [mm] [TeX Gyre Pagella Math]
\definefontfamily [test] [tt] [Fira Mono]
\setupbodyfont    [test,12pt]

\starttext
Test \type{Text} with $\mathtt{TEST}$
\stoptext
```

which currently outputs:

[image: strange mathtt]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set Fira Mono as fallback for the `uppercasemonospace` and `lowercasemonospace` range.

```
\definefontfamily [test] [rm] [TeX Gyre Pagella]
\definefallbackfamily [test] [mm] [Fira Mono] [offset=uppercasemonospace,range=uppercasenormal,force=yes]
\definefallbackfamily [test] [mm] [Fira Mono] [offset=lowercasemonospace,range=lowercasenormal,force=yes]
\definefontfamily [test] [mm] [TeX Gyre Pagella Math]
\definefontfamily [test] [tt] [Fira Mono]
\setupbodyfont    [test,12pt]

\starttext
Test \type{Text} with $\mathtt{TEST}$
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is this documented anywhere (including the other possible options)?

Comment: @TeXnician https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definefontfallback

Comment: Thanks. Obviously I'm still missing some obvious associations :)

Comment: @TeXnician `\definefontfamily` and `\definefallbackfamily` only add name lookup on top of `\definetypeface` and `\definefontfallback`, respectively.  My recommendation is to use the latter two, because name lookup is much slower than file lookup and relies on an up-to-date name database.