# How to activate font fallbacks on typefaces in ConTeXt?

Tags: fonts, context

This is a follow-up to my [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/484636/124577) about setting the tt font in mathtt. As [Henri Menke](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10995/henri-menke) stated in a [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484636/how-to-use-tt-font-in-mathtt-in-context#comment1227321_484719) using typefaces should be preferred over font families. So I tried to convert the code given in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/484719/124577). The result is the following MWE:

```
\starttypescript[test]
    \definetypeface [test] [rm] [serif] [pagella]
    \definetypeface [test] [tt] [mono] [firacode]
    \definefontfallback [ttupper] [firacode] [uppercasenormal] [offset=uppercasemonospace,force=yes]
    \definefontfallback [ttlower] [firacode] [lowercasenormal] [offset=lowercasemonospace,force=yes]
    \definetypeface [test] [mm] [math] [pagella] [default] [fallbacks={ttlower,ttupper}]
\stoptypescript
\setupbodyfont  [test,12pt]

\starttext
Test \type{Text} with $\mathtt{TEST}$
\stoptext
```

Unfortunately, ConTeXt does not use the fallbacks I specified. How does the fallback mechanism work with typefaces?

Comment: `\definefontfallback` needs a font lookup as the second argument, either via `name:<name>`, or `file:<file>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use fallbacks with `\definefontsynonym`, so you have to define a typescript.  Of course the typescript definition would go in an environment file in your larger project.  You can also take a look at [this answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/466661) to find out how to install fonts and typescript system-wide.

```
\loadtypescriptfile[texgyre]

\definefontfallback [firaoverpagella] [file:FiraMono-Regular.otf] [uppercasenormal] [offset=uppercasemonospace,force=yes]
\definefontfallback [firaoverpagella] [file:FiraMono-Regular.otf] [lowercasenormal] [offset=lowercasemonospace,force=yes]

\starttypescript [mono] [firamono] [name]
    \definefontsynonym [Mono]     [file:FiraMono-Regular.otf]
    \definefontsynonym [MonoBold] [file:FiraMono-Bold.otf]
\stoptypescript

\starttypescript [math] [firaoverpagella]
    \definefontsynonym [MathRoman] [texgyrepagella-math] [features={math\mathsizesuffix,mathextra},fallbacks=firaoverpagella]
\stoptypescript

\starttypescript [pagella-with-fira]
    \definetypeface [\typescriptone] [rm] [serif] [pagella]          [default]
    \definetypeface [\typescriptone] [ss] [sans]  [pagella]          [default]
    \definetypeface [\typescriptone] [tt] [mono]  [firamono]         [default]
    \definetypeface [\typescriptone] [mm] [math]  [firaoverpagella]  [default]
    \quittypescriptscanning
\stoptypescript

\setupbodyfont [pagella-with-fira,12pt]

\starttext
Test \type{Text} with $\mathtt{TEST}$
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: I couldn't test yet, but according to `setup-en.pdf` there is a `fallbacks` option key for `\definetypeface`. Is that deprecated or just infunctional?

Comment: @TeXnician I could only find [one reference to `fallbacks`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/32e6c720c4f84f112596c6b4a75193f99e9be158/tex/context/base/mkiv/type-ini.mkvi#L551-L563) in the `\definetypeface` source, which is not very insightful.  Also none of the bundled typescripts seems to use `fallbacks` with `\definetypeface`.  I think it just doesn't work.